# Как нарисовать пиксель в picture box?

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

Ковыряюсь в Windows Forms. По итогу мне нужно будет имея какую-то функцию (математическую) строить график. В связи с этим хочется понять, как изобразить на форме точку.

Answer (score 1):

С помощью Bitmap, а именно функцией `Bitmap.SetPixel().`

Но если вы хотите рисовать графики, то это не лучший способ. В Windows Forms есть элемент Chart. Пользоваться им можно примерно так:

```
chart->Series[0]->Points->AddXY(x, f(x));
```

Там можно настроить тип интерполирования функции. Думаю, spline будет наиболее подходящий для вас.

Answer (score 0):

Этот ответ был в английском so

```
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(aBrush, x, y, 1, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

В Windows Forms для построения графиков используется инструмент Chart. 
Для выбора типа "График" выберите в Properties -> Series -> Revenue property -> ChartType. В выпадающем списке выберите необходимый тип графика. 
Методы Chart рассмотрим на примере следующего кода по построению функций косинуса и синуса с комментариями:

```
private void buttonCalc_Click(object sender,

EventArgs e)

{

// Считываем с формы требуемые значения

double Xmin = double.Parse(textBoxXmin.Text);

double Xmax = double.Parse(textBoxXmax.Text);

double Step = double.Parse(textBoxStep.Text);



// Количество точек графика

int count = (int)Math.Ceiling((Xmax - Xmin) / Step)

+ 1;



// Массив значений X – общий для обоих графиков

double[] x = new double[count];



// Два массива Y – по одному для каждого графика

double[] y1 = new double[count];

double[] y2 = new double[count];



// Расчитываем точки для графиков функции

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)

{

// Вычисляем значение X

x[i] = Xmin + Step * i;

// Вычисляем значение функций в точке X

y1[i] = Math.Sin(x[i]);

y2[i] = Math.Cos(x[i]);

}



// Настраиваем оси графика

chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = Xmin;

chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = Xmax;



// Определяем шаг сетки

chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Interval = Step;



// Добавляем вычисленные значения в графики

chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(x, y1);

chart1.Series[1].Points.DataBindXY(x, y2);

}
```

Вот [ссылка на пример](http://life-prog.ru/2_30188_kak-stroitsya-grafik-s-pomoshchyu-elementa-upravleniya-Chart.html).